# How to do vertical header column table in datatable JavaScript?

Tags: datatables

How to do vertical header columns in datatable ?

[image: It is like following now]

It should be as follows and working as datatble.
[image]

Comment: Datatables is a jQuery plugin that you use from Javascript, it doesn't have anything to do with PHP.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do vertical header columns using datatable JS. However,you can create the prototype html and design the first column to look like header and then apply the fixedHeader property to be able to scroll with left column intact.

```js
this.dTable = $('#vdatatable').DataTable({
    dom:            'ftip',
    stateSave:      saveState,
    retrieve:       true,
    autoWidth:      false,
    info:           true,
    paging:         false,
    scrollY:        false,
    scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: false,
    fixedHeader:    true,
    fixedColumns:   {
        leftColumns: 1
    },
}):
```

```css
.vertical-header-column {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #C6DBEA;
}
```

```html
<table id="vdatatable" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-column="Username" class="vertical-header-column">Username</th>
            <th data-column="Balakumar">Balakumar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>            
            <th data-column="Username" class="vertical-header-column">Col1</th>
            <td data-column="Balakumar">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th data-column="Username" class="vertical-header-column">Col2</th>
            <td data-column="Balakumar">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th data-column="Username" class="vertical-header-column">Col3</th>
            <td data-column="Balakumar">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>        
            <th data-column="Username" class="vertical-header-column">Col4</th>
            <td data-column="Balakumar">85</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for something called matrix transpose in mathematics. to get transpose of a matrix/table convert rows to columns.

```
<?php

$table = [
    ['Username', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4'],
    ['Balakumar', 3, 2, 5, 85]
];

function printTable($rows) {
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        foreach ($row as $value) {
            printf("%10s", $value);
        }
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
}


function transposeTable($table) {
    $rowsCount = count($table);
    $columnsCount = count($table[0]);

    for ($row = 0; $row < $rowsCount; $row++) {
        for($column = 0; $column < $columnsCount; $column++) {
            $transpose[$column][$row] = $table[$row][$column];
        }
    }
    return $transpose;

}

echo 'Table :' . PHP_EOL;
printTable($table);
echo 'Transpose:' . PHP_EOL;
printTable(transposeTable($table));

?>
```

Output:

```
  Username      Col1      Col2      Col3      Col4  

  Balakumar       3         2         5        85   

  Username        Balakumar

  Col1         3      

  Col2         2

  Col3         5

  Col4        85
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use html property. Try to use  tags. Fill this tags with PHP. Maybe a foreach will be useful ! 
Hopefully I helped you !