# Vertically align table header using DataTable

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, datatables

I've got a table of about 1K rows and using `DataTable` for pagination. Is there anyway I can get the tables to have vertical columns in medium/small devices?

This seems to work with `display: inline-block` properties when I don't use `DataTable` but does not seem to work with DataTable in place.

Sample markup of my table

```
<style type="text/css">
   #vertical thead,#vertical tbody{
   display:inline-block;
   }
</style>
<table id="vertical">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="3">Header 1</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="3">Header 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="3">Header 3</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>row 1</td>
         <td>row 1</td>
         <td>row 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>row 2</td>
         <td>row 2</td>
         <td>row 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>row 3</td>
         <td>row 3</td>
         <td>row 3</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

This aligns it the way I want it but does not work with DataTable-

Header 1  row 1  row 1 row 1
Header 2  row 2  row 2 row 2
Header 3  row 3  row 3 row 3

Tried using responsive properties to initialize `DataTable` and referred examples [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/), all to no avail.

If it is not possible using `DataTable`, it'd be great if you can suggest any alternatives, to achieve pagination and responsive vertical columns. Using `bootstrap 3` and `jquery` btw.

Comment: There is actually a responsive plugin for DataTables.

Comment: Not working, i guess the responsive extension of datatables is just to play around with columns and related data, nothing to make the table columns vertical.

Comment: you have to look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48288757/5813861)

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I did try this .. but figured out using a different pagination library gives me the flexibility to maintain my mark up the way I want. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve vertical column headers for a table using `DataTable`. One way to overcome this is to create a prototype html as suggested by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442764/how-to-do-vertical-header-column-table-in-datatable-javascript#48288757).

Alternatively, if all you are looking for is pagination, there are several other pagination libraries out there which are light weight and support custom CSS rules and templating without enforcing any fixed rules. I ended up using [pagination.js](http://pagination.js.org/) and custom creating my table for different viewports using HandleBars and plain old CSS.

An example of integrating pagination.js with handlebars [here](https://github.com/superRaytin/paginationjs/issues/27).